# Встроить .txt в .exe

Tags: c#, wpf

Почему для текстовых файлов не получается задать свойства Resource + Do not copy, с их загрузкой по относительной ссылке, а для изображений - легко.

Это все работает:

```
Source="Images\img.JPG"

bit.UriSource = new Uri("Images/img.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
```

А здесь уже нет:

```
string path = Convert.ToString(new Uri(@"Text\myText.txt", UriKind.Relative));
```

Читаю рекомендацию:
"для приложений WPF рекомендуется всегда использовать значение Resource (Ресурс)". Но так у меня не получается добраться до файла по относительному пути.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"Images/img.jpg"` не является путём к файлу. Поэтому и не надейтесь получить «путь» к файлу и манипулировать файлом через путь.

Вы должны получить stream и читать из него. Например, так:

```
var uri = new Uri("Text/myText.txt", UriKind.Relative);
var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
var content = new StreamReader(stream.Stream).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понятно.

Comment: @UggoFantozzi: Пожалуйста!